# python iris detection decision tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, decision-tree

i am trying to learn about decision trees and I found a tutorial about the subject. The goal of the tutorial is to decide if a flower is a special type of flower called iris but i seem to run into some errors that i hope somebody got the answer to i get two errors like the following:

iris: Bunch
iris: inner_f
Instance of 'tuple' has no 'target' member

and

iris: Bunch
iris: inner_f
Instance of 'tuple' has no 'data' member

here is the code:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#load iris data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
x = iris.data
y = iris.target
d = [{"sepal_length":row[0], 
      "sepal_width":row[1], 
      "petal_length":row[2], 
      "petal_width":row[3]} for row in x]
df = pd.DataFrame(d) # construct dataframe
df["types"] = y # assign types
df = df.sample(frac=1.0) # random shuffle rows
df.head()
```

Is there anybody that knows why i get these errors?

Comment: The code you've provided does not produce the error for me.

Comment: What error did you receive. Your code seems to work fine on my end.

Comment: works for me as well.. are you using a very old version of sklearn

Comment: huh well thats sad the good old "it works on my machine". :)